# How to make preg_match accent insensitive?

Tags: php, php-8

I want to make preg_match accent insensitive but it doesn't work.

```
$haystack = 'été';
$needle = 'ete';

if (preg_match('#'.$needle.'#ui', $haystack, $matches)) {
    echo $haystack.' matches.';
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the modifier `u` allows to process the string with multibyte characters. But it does not allow transliteration of accents. You can use `iconv()` to handle this case.

```php
$haystack = 'nous sommes en été.';
$needle   = 'ete';

$haystack = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $haystack);
if (preg_match('#' . $needle . '#ui', $haystack, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(3) "ete"
}
```